# how can i close the gab between the rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have six blocks. I combined the top and bottom and now there is a gap. anyway to move this row up without breaking anything?I would like to know how to solve this issue with bootstrap.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="portfolio-item.html">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio" src="https://placehold.it/600x250">
                </a>
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="portfolio-item.html">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio" src="https://placehold.it/600x250">
                </a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <a href="portfolio-item.html">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio" src="https://placehold.it/400x450">ss
                </a>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="portfolio-item.html">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio" src="https://placehold.it/600x250">
                </a>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="portfolio-item.html">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio" src="https://placehold.it/600x250">
                </a>
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
```

Comment: Just a bit of guidance, you should avoid "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" there really is no need to do that, and it's not recommended. Use CSS for presentation.

Comment: you should avoid changing the titles of your questions. If a new question arises, then you can ask it via comments or an edit on the actual post.

Comment: i made changes to the design based on the suggestions--only reason i changed the title, to better fit the updated content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gaps are coming from the padding on the bootstrap rows, create a class to remove the padding and add it to each of your rows.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class='col-lg-8'>
<div class='row'>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <a href="portfolio-item.html">
         <img class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio" src="https://placehold.it/600x250">
    </a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <a href="portfolio-item.html">
        <img class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio" src="https://placehold.it/600x250">
    </a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <a href="portfolio-item.html">
         <img class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio" src="https://placehold.it/600x250">
    </a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <a href="portfolio-item.html">
        <img class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio" src="https://placehold.it/600x250">
    </a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
    <a href="portfolio-item.html">
        <img class="img-responsive img-home-portfolio" src="https://placehold.it/400x450">ss
    </a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
</div>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
```

Comment: i didnt want to merge the areas you have merged. i like the default gap bewteen the rows but not the huge gap in the middle. You  have to click full page view to see the big space. is there a way to tighten up the gap?

Comment: @Vzupo updated the markup, to match what I think you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This answer was posted before OP changed his question's title....

Keeping the answer simple, you could structure the page like following:

```
<div>
    <div id="col1"></div>
    <div id="col2"></div>
</div>

<div id="tallBlock">

</div>

<div>
    <div id="col3"></div>
    <div id="col4"></div>
</div>
```

If you use column-count on the top and bottom divs, then they would be split into 2 columns. You should manually set the height on the col divs to ensure they don't try to flow into the second column when they are not post to.